# PL SQL comma delimited to JSON array conversion

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have values in one column with delimit as comma.

Col1

a,b,c,d

I want to convert this into JSON Array. I know JSON_ARRAY function is available in PL/SQL from 12.2 onwards. But JSON_ARRAY converts multiple columns to the array. I have values in the single column.

output: ["a","b","c","d"]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054) instead of `JSON_ARRAY()` function without using PL/SQL, after converting those letters into row-wise style through splitting by commas such as

```
WITH t(id,col1) AS
(
 SELECT 1,'a,b,c,d' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'d,e,f,g,h,i' FROM dual
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,'[^,]+',1,level) AS col, id
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(col1,',')+1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR col1 = col1
)    
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(col ORDER BY col RETURNING VARCHAR2(100)) As "JSON value"
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bf386278b26710d1112717a1175a3c4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just use replace:

```sql
SELECT '["'
       ||REPLACE(REPLACE(col1,'"','\"'),',','","')
       ||'"]' AS json_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Or, in PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  col1 VARCHAR2(50) := 'a,b,c,d';
  json VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
 json := '["'||REPLACE(REPLACE(col1,'"','\"'),',','","')||'"]';
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(json);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9677be2b0f5037792e78c331ea1de1da)*